# Error 404 en HGitHub Page

Tags: github

estoy intentando hacer la implementación de mi primera página, pero hasta ahora no he podido.
Estoy intentando con GitHub pages.
En teoría ya está todo listo como para funcionar, pero cuando abro el enlace que me da GitHub obtengo un error 404.

Todavía me cuesta entender cuál es el nombre del repositorio y cuáles son los pasos que debía hacer. Seguí la documentación que figura en GitHub page, que es super básica y no pasó nada.

El repositorio está aquí: https://github.com/nicobonder/contentwriter.git y la dirección que me dio fue: https://nicobonder.github.io/contentwriter/

Luego intenté hacerlo desde de GIT y cuando hago el push, obtengo esto:
$ git push nicobonder/contentwriter
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream nicobonder/contentwriter master
```

Y si hago:
git push --set-upstream nicobonder/contentwriter master

Me aparece:
fatal: 'nicobonder/contentwriter' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Así que ya no sé qué hacer ni cuál es el error.
Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Gracias.

Comment: Debes poner el index html en tu directorio raíz. De hecho si accedes al enlace https://nicobonder.github.io/contentwriter/Views/index.html podrás ver tu página.

Comment: Gracias @JaimeMenéndez Se abre la pagina, pero la veo como si no estuviera conectada al css y al JS. Tienes idea por qué puede ser?

Comment: es que las rutas relativas no estan correctas

Comment: Perdon, soy muy nuevo en esto. A qué te refieres con las rutas relativas?   Si abro el proyecto de forma local, usando el Live Server de VS Code, se ve el sitio con el CSS y el JS.

Comment: Por ejemplo, cuando pones el src de una imagen, en esa misma página que te mandé pones `src="/Ilustraciones/sentado.png"`. Eso significa que tu código buscará en el directorio actual que es views una carpeta que se llame `Ilustraciones` y que contenga un archivo `sentado.png`. La carpeta ilustraciones NO está en el directorio actual (que es `Views`), está en un directorio por encima, por lo que lo correcto sería:  `src="../Ilustraciones/sentado.png"`

Comment: Así con todas las rutas. En tu header el `href` al css debería ser `href="../Styles/estilo.css"`

Comment: De hecho, si abres https://nicobonder.github.io/contentwriter/Views/index.html con chrome developer tools y editas las rutas como te comenté, verás que poco a poco van apareciendo las imágenes y el contenido como quieres.

Comment: Ah ok, entiendo. Pero sí está bien hecho (excepto por un par de errores que acabo de corregir), pero el CSS y el JS están bien linkeados al html, por lo que se debería ver. También ya puse el index.html en la carpeta principal (que la llamé Codigos) y ahora puedo abrir el sitio haciendo: https://nicobonder.github.io/contentwriter/

Comment: Tienes que poner un punto delante de cada ruta: `href="./Styles/estilo.css"`, o bien `src="./Ilustraciones/sentado.png"`